# Apostrophe Issue on Foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

I use the Foursquare API to search for venues. It has been working well up until recently when I tried finding a venue with an apostrophe in the name.

For example searching for: `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?intent=match&ll=51.308251643957,1.069603024223&query=Tyler's Kiln`

I have even tried it on the API Explorer on the Foursquare website and had no luck.

Comment: Have you tried `Tyler%27s%20Kiln`?

Answer (score 0):

Brandon's comment is correct. You should url encode your query: `Tyler%27s%20Kiln`